# Excel Querytable Refresh only works once

Tags: excel, vba, oledb

I am adding a ListObject to an Excel 2007 Workbook using VBA.  The ListObject is to have a QueryTable behind it, linking to an Access database.  The code looks like this:

```
Dim l As ListObject
Dim c As ADODB.Connection
Dim r As ADODB.Recordset

Set c = New ADODB.Connection
c.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=myAccessDatabasePath;Persist Security Info=False;"

Set r = New ADODB.Recordset
r.Open "Select * From myTable", c

Set l = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcQuery, r, True, xlYes, Range("A1"))
l.QueryTable.Refresh False

'this line causes an error
l.QueryTable.Refresh False
```

Essentially the problem is that I cannot refresh the table more than once.  The Refresh button on both the Data and the Table Design ribbons is greyed out.  I have tried similar code without using Listobjects (i.e. just QueryTables) and get the same problem.  I have tried refreshing the underlying connection object and again, get the same problem.

I've spent all morning Googling to no avail.

Is this a bug, designed behaviour or (most likely) am I doing something stupid?

Many thanks in advance,

Steve

Comment: Because the First refresh hasn't finished yet.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that.  Even if I removed both refreshes and refreshed via Excel instead, I can see the data arriving on the worksheet (only a dozen rows or so).  However, the option to refresh again is greyed out.  Even if I close and reopen it, the option is still greyed out.  I think something is happening to the connection object - but I can't work out what.

Comment: Besides which, the 'false' parameter after the refresh method is supposed to prevent the thing from refreshing in the background (I think).  So if my understanding is correct the code ought to wait until it had finished anyway before starting the next row.  Thanks though.

Comment: The background refresh is sometimes overridden if any table in the workbook has the `Connection Property` of to not Enable Background Refresh. But with the new data my solution is not for your specific issue. Just a thought have you tried changing the `Persist Security Info=False` to True so that it will retain the security information

Comment: Thanks again.  Just tried that, no luck I'm afraid.  I'm beginning to think that it might be easiest to just write my own little bit of code to refresh my list objects (i.e. just looping through the recordset), as I've also experienced a couple of catastrophic Excel crashes today when playing around with this stuff.

Comment: I've worked a lot with external data and I never knew you could use an ADODB recordset as the Source. But I can confirm that it works, then grays out the refresh button (Win7, XL2010). If you record a macro it doesn't use ADODB, but uses a SourceType of xlSrcExternal and passes in the connection string. I wonder if you did it that way instead of ADODB if that would free up the refresh (and we'd both learn something).

Comment: Dick - thanks for your comment.  I was just following some Microsoft help file, which used a recordset as one of the params for the Add method.  Using the xlSrcExternal with the other params the same leaves me with the same error.  However, I did give the macro recorder a go (I have used it less and less since Excel 2007 came along - there seems to be quite a lot of stuff in Excel that the macro recorder doesn't really help with) and managed to get it to work.  Hoorah!  I will post the code below in an answer in case anyone else gets stuck with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I got it to work.  The macro recorder (thanks for the suggestion Dick) was actually useful for once.

```
Dim s As Worksheet
Dim l As ListObject

Set s = ActiveSheet
Set l = s.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=myDatabasePath;", True, xlYes, Range("A1"))

l.QueryTable.CommandType = xlCmdTable
l.QueryTable.CommandText = "mytable"

l.QueryTable.Refresh False

'this now works!
l.QueryTable.Refresh False
```

Answer (score 1):

This is ***UNTESTED*** but it still should work, it will check if the table is already in a refresh and if it is, it will wait 1 second and check again until it is no longer refreshing then it will continue

```
Dim l As ListObject
Dim c As ADODB.Connection
Dim r As ADODB.Recordset

Set c = New ADODB.Connection
c.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=myAccessDatabasePath;Persist Security Info=False;"

Set r = New ADODB.Recordset
r.Open "Select * From myTable", c

Set l = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcQuery, r, True, xlYes, Range("A1"))
    With l
        .QueryTable.Refresh False

             Do while .Refreshing 
                 Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
             Loop

         'this line causes an error
        .QueryTable.Refresh False

End With
```

Comment: Thanks again.  It doesn't work, but as I mentioned in the comments above I don't think that this is the problem.  The initial refresh takes well under a second to happen.  Even if I close and reopen Excel (and come back from lunch) there doesn't appear to be any way to re-refresh the query.